# Mounting an NFS or SMB share onto OSX only while connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, nfs, server-message-block

I'm setting up my machine to connect to network share resources at the place I work (there are NFS shares and SMB shares). This access is only possible through VPN. So my question is, Is there a way to get OSX to only attempt to automount an NFS or SMB share if it is connected through VPN?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an easy way to do that ?

Comment: No, sadly. I'll look into ptman's solution sometime this week and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X has autofs, which, by default, is configured to do NFS automounts under `/net`. So you should be able to just `cd /net/$hostname/$share`.